# googleAnalyticsR 403 user permission

Tags: r, google-analytics-api

I am cyciling through 50 GA accounts and there is one with user permission that I do not have access to the error I am getting is...

Error : API returned: User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.
Error in error_check(out) : 
  API returned: User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.

I new to R and am wondering if I can write a trycatch method to skip this account and continue the method. At the moment the process stops with a Teequest Status Code:403/

```
library(googleAnalyticsR)
library(tidyverse)

#settings
start_date <- as.character(Sys.Date()-31)
end_date <- as.character(Sys.Date()-1)
metrics <- c("sessions", "pageviews")
dimensions <- "year"

#Authorize Google Analytics R- this will open a webpage
#You must be logged into your Google Analytics account on your web browser
ga_auth()

account_summary <- ga_account_list() 


#Add the start and end date to the date frame, as well as some columns to use to populate the metrics
account_summary$start_date <- start_date
account_summary$end_date <- end_date


# cycle through the list of views, pull the data, and add it to the
#account_summary

for (i in 1:nrow(account_summary)){

  view_id <- account_summary$viewId[i]

  ga_data <- google_analytics_4(viewId = view_id,
                                date_range = c(start_date,end_date),
                                metrics = metrics,
                                dimensions = dimensions)

  # This query might return multiple rows (if it spans a year boundary), so
  #collapse and clean up

  ga_data <- summarise(ga_data,
                       sessions = sum(sessions),
                       pageviews = sum(pageviews))

  #add the totals to the account summary

  account_summary$sessions[i] <- ga_data$sessions
  account_summary$pageviews[i] <- ga_data$pageviews

}

# Make a more compact set of data

clean_summary <- select(account_summary,
                        Account = accountName,
                        Property + webPropertyName,
                        View = viewName,
                        Type = type,
                        Level = level,
                        'Start Date' = start_date,
                        'End Date' = end_date,
                        Sessions = sessions,
                        Pageviews = pageviews)

write.csv (clean_summary, "summary_results.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Sorry about the spelling mistakes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tryCatch` like this:

```
...

ga_data <- tryCatch(google_analytics_4(viewId = view_id,
                            date_range = c(start_date,end_date),
                            metrics = metrics,
                            dimensions = dimensions),
                    error = function(ex){
                    warning(ex)
                    NULL
                      })

...
```

The example turns the error into a warning instead, and returns a `NULL`

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me. Im finding this trycatch statement is not working for me. The account thats causing the error is a google demo account that cant be removed as there are no admin privileges.
Error : API returned: User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.
Error in error_check(out) : 
  API returned: User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.

Comment: Do I call the specific error in the error in the fuction or just use ex in the brackets e.g. 
 = function(  Request failed [403] )

Comment: It changed returning an error to a warning but still returns, so it should work if the syntax is correct. You could optionally drop the warning line, or catch specific errors by examine the string. Try putting a browser() in the error block so you can see what is returned in ex and adapt to your needs